# Calculating electrical limits of a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a small DC motor left over from a crappy toy car, that I want to reuse for a small project.

How can I find out the voltage/current requirements/limits if all I have is the motor in hand without a specs sheet?

Comment: Are there no markings or anything on the motor?

Comment: There might be, but it would require me to break open the toy car's frame, which I'm planning to use as the base for my project anyway.  Is that the only option?

Comment: The usual hint to the voltage would be it's likely to be the same as the voltage of the batteries the car was running from especially for a cheap one.

Comment: It had 5x AA batteries...  So can I assume the motor requires 7.5 volts?

Comment: @KevinSoviero, I'd say so. It may be a 6V motor but there's always a bit of leeway, they might have aimed a bit higher so rechargeables and fairly flat batteries would work OK as well.

Comment: If the car isn't toast best bet would be to examine it *in situ* using a multimeter/oscilloscope to probe the voltage or PWM duty cycle (if it has varying speed)

Comment: FWIW: Battery count MAY mislead. Some toys use two batteries to make a -ve and +ve supply - which makes motor direction control easier. In some cases they may have a separate electronics supply. So, not likely here BUT you could have 2 2 1 arrangement giving +3/-3 1.5 .Looking at / measuring how the batteries are connected will show if the above is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the voltage - if you removed it from the toy what was the voltage being used to turn it?

With that voltage measure the no load speed and current (see below)

[image]

*As a rough guide small DC motors turn at around 1000 rpm per volt.*

(The next bit is where it gets a tricky without proper test equipment). You need to load (add a breaking torque) to the motor and measure the results. By any convenient means, keeping the voltage to the motor the same, slow the speed of rotation by about 20 %. Measure the current at this speed.

This will give you **a rough idea** of how the motor current/speed will change when loaded. (remember the current is proportional to torque).

I don't recommend a stall current test - this tends to burn the motor out.

[image]

Comment: Wow!  I wasn't expecting such a professional/detailed answer...  Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the cell count is an obvious clue - though bipolar H bridge drivers can easily eat a volt or two under load, compared to a direct connection through switches or relays or with an FET driver.

But motor ratings are always relative, depending on a variety of factors, rather than exact anyway.

Consider what the limitations are:

1) Thermal - how hot does it get?  How hot can it tolerate getting?  You may be able to cool some parts, but can you cool all of it?  If it is not uncomfortable to touch it is probably okay; some motors such as in RC aircraft or racecars are routinely run much hotter than you would want to touch, but may have relatively short lifetimes.

2) Demagnetization from excessive field strength (probably not an issue here) or a combination of that and heat (slightly less unlikely)

3) Mechanical stress on brushes and bearings

Realistically, for a little toy motor, excessive heat is going to be your primary indication that you are overdriving it, or driving it hard at too high a duty cycle.  Going the other way, not spinning is an indication that you are not providing sufficient electrical power.  And not spinning (fast enough) while overheating is an indication that the motor is undersized for the job.